# how to send push notification to arduino

Tags: push-notification, arduino, iot

I would like to know if there is anything like GCM for arduino.

I'm working on a project where I need to send push notifications to the arduino connected with WiFi shield. Arduino then will do some action based on the notification it gets or sync up with the server data.
Any advice on how I need to proceed would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can send push notification to Arduino. There are multiple ways from where you can send push notification to Arduino.

I am using push notification from Parse.com.To send push notification from Parse just register with Parse.com and create account there.
Once you create account,you can send push notification from Parse dashboard.

To receive notification on Arduino you need to write sketch on Arduino, following is sketch for help.

Include Parse library to make sure following code will work.

```
/***************************************************************************************************************************
  setup function
****************************************************************************************************************************/

void setup() {

  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (!Serial);

  Parse.begin("***E0uUjQkMa7nj5D5BALvzegzfyVNSG22BD2FJ", "umPSsggp5JgMFmSHfloewW5oixlM5ibt9LBS***");
    // In this example, we associate this device with a pre-generated installation

   Parse.getInstallationId();
   Parse.startPushService();

}//setup function block


void loop() {

if (Parse.pushAvailable()) {

    Serial.println("Start push");

    ParsePush push = Parse.nextPush();
    // Print whole JSON body

    String message = push.getJSONBody();
    // Serial.print("New push message size: ");
    //  Serial.println(message.length());
    // Serial.print("New push message content: ");
    Serial.println(message);
    // Do something with the push
    // IMPORTANT, close your push message
    push.close();
    checkStatus(message);   
    Serial.println("End Push");


  }//if push notification block

} //loop
```

You can read documentation here https://parse.com/docs/arduino/guide#push-notifications.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run an HTTP server on the wifi shield which accepts requests, then send such a request from your outside system (command line on your desktop, IFTTT recipe, etc.)

I'm assuming this is one of the older 8bit Arduinos (since you mention the wifishield rather than something like the Yun with a Linux partition), so you will need to write a http server sketch on the Arduino.

Here is tutorial for a simple HTTP server with the wifi shield from arduino.cc

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer